# Set AutoCompleteTextView drop down height to 60dp above bottom

Tags: android

I am trying to set the drop down height of my `AutoCompleteTextView` to be 60dp above the bottom of screen.

```
displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
WindowManager windowmanager = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
windowmanager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = Math.round(displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density - 60);
edtSeach.setDropDownHeight(height);
```

This works on my Huawei P9 Lite running Android 7.0.

[image: dropdown1]

However, when I try on emulator running Android 6.0, it is not working.

[image: dropdown2]

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem myself by implementing custom class which extend `AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView`.

```
public void showDropDown() {
        Rect displayFrame = new Rect();
        getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(displayFrame);

        int[] locationOnScreen = new int[2];
        getLocationOnScreen(locationOnScreen);

        int bottom = locationOnScreen[1] + getHeight();
        int availableHeightBelow = displayFrame.bottom - bottom;
        Resources r = getResources();
        int bottomHeight = Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 60, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
        int downHeight = availableHeightBelow - bottomHeight;
        setDropDownHeight(downHeight);

        super.showDropDown();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`android:dropDownHeight="100dp"`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#attr_android:dropDownHeight)

> Specifies the basic height of the `dropdown`. Its value may be a dimension (such as "12dip") for a constant height, `fill_parent` or `match_parent` to fill the height of the screen, or `wrap_content` to match the height of the content of the drop down.
>
> May be a dimension value, which is a floating point number appended with a unit such as "14.5sp". Available units are: px (pixels), dp (density-independent pixels), sp (scaled pixels based on preferred font size), in (inches), and mm (millimeters).

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
 <AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dropDownHeight="100dp"/>
```

Comment: Why set it as 100dp?

Comment: Set as 100dp makes my drop down height too narrow. I would like to extend it to full height but 60dp above the bottom of screen.